Flask and Twillio Webscoket Streaming
I have transcriber.py
import asyncio
import websockets
import json
from VRD4_optimize import user_chatbot_conversation  # Import your conversation function


# # Define the function to handle incoming WebSocket messages
async def handle_message(websocket, path):
    # async for message in websocket:
        try:
                print("Client connected")
                audio_file = await websocket.recv()
                with open("received_audio.wav", "wb") as f:
                    f.write(audio_file)
                # Process the user input using your existing chatbot logic
                # Replace this line with your actual chatbot logic
                chatbot_response = await user_chatbot_conversation("received_audio.wav")
                
                output_path = "/home/ec2-user/new_rag/output.wav"

                # Read the processed audio file
                with open(output_path, "rb") as f:
                    processed_audio_data = f.read()

                # Send the processed audio data back to the client
                await websocket.send(processed_audio_data)
        except Exception as e:
            # If an error occurs, send an error response back to the client
            error_response = {
                "type": "error",
                "content": f"An error occurred: {str(e)}"
            }
            await websocket.send(json.dumps(error_response))
 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    server = websockets.serve(handle_message, "0.0.0.0", 8768)  # Listen on all interfaces
    print("WebSocket server started.")

    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(server)
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()

Then app.py
client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)

@app.route('/make_call', methods=['POST'])
def make_call():
    try:
        # Make a call using Twilio
        call = client.calls.create(
            url="http://server-ip:5000",
            to=to_number,
            from_=from_number
        )

        print("Call SID:", call.sid)

        return 'Call initiated successfully', 200

    except Exception as e:
        print("Exception:", e)
        return 'Error initiating call', 500

@app.route("/", methods=['POST'])
def twilio_webhook():
    # # Generate TwiML with the audio file URL
    # twiml_response = generate_twiml_with_stream()

    # return twiml_response
    if request.method == 'POST':
        xml = f"""
        <Response>
            <Connect>
                <Stream url="wss://server-ip:8768/" />
            </Connect>
        </Response>
        """
        return Response(xml, mimetype='text/xml')
    else:
        return f"Real-time phone call transcription app"

# Start WebSocket server
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # server = websockets.serve(handle_message, "0.0.0.0", 8768)  # Listen on all interfaces
    # print("WebSocket server started.")

    # Start Flask app
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)

When I run the webscoket seperately and flask app seperately it runs in a specific server ip. When i make the call and attend stream function get triggers but when conencting to webscoket it gets an error when i checked the twillio logs.
Error: 31901Stream - WebSocket - Connection Timeout
Trying to fix it but couldn't able to achieve the connection. Kindly help me to connect with the websocket and stream audio to websocket function.

always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

In this case this the full error message given in the twilio logs "Error: 31901Stream - WebSocket - Connection Timeout". What to do now

don't you get error message when you run code console/terminal? maybe first you should run code without try/except to see full error messages (in console/terminal).
